# Azure Logic App HTTP Action step - dynamically get endOfDate date

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

i have an azure logic app with recurrence that will call api endpoint every midnight, im passing in two date properties in my request body that will include start of day and end of day.

Logic app has expression startOfDay() however they dont have endOfDay(), how can I dynamically get end of day in UTC format like startOfDay() does?
Thanks

this is how my request body looks like but its also complaining about @startOfDay()

```
{
 "organizationId": 'f41186b0-7f09-42c5-8a9d-81a2ad2b0e61',
 "attemptedDeliveries": true,
 "cancelDateStart": @{startOfDay()},
 "cancelDateEnd": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct expression for endOfDay but one of the workarounds is to `addToTime` and 'subtractFromTime' from [startOfDay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#startofday) to get the endOfDay. Consider I'm taking the timestamp to be `UtcNow()` and to calculate the endOfDay I'm using the below expression.

```
subtractFromTime(addToTime(outputs('startOfDay'),1,'Day','o'),1,'Second','yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')
```

I'm using Parse Json in order to retrieve the inner Json details for future use. By doing this, you can have a custom JSON created using `Compose()` connector.

[image]

**Result:-**

[image]

**Codeview**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": {
                    "attemptedDeliveries": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['attemptedDeliveries']",
                    "cancelDateEnd": "@{outputs('endOfDay')}",
                    "cancelDateStart": "@{outputs('startOfDay')}",
                    "organizationId": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['organizationId']}"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "endOfDay": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "attemptedDeliveries": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "cancelDateEnd": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "cancelDateStart": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "organizationId": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "endOfDay": {
                "inputs": "@subtractFromTime(addToTime(startOfDay(utcNow()),1,'Day','o'),1,'Second','yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "startOfDay": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "startOfDay": {
                "inputs": "@startOfDay(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Here is the json that I'm receiving from my body of Http trigger

```
{
 "organizationId": "f41186b0-7f09-42c5-8a9d-81a2ad2b0e61",
 "attemptedDeliveries": true,
 "cancelDateStart": "",
 "cancelDateEnd": ""
}
```

### Updated Answer

---

After the follow up here my logic app

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**Codeview**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "endOfDay": {
                "inputs": "@subtractFromTime(addToTime(startOfDay(utcNow()),1,'Day','o'),1,'Second','yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "startOfDay": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "startOfDay": {
                "inputs": "@startOfDay(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 30
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 30
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

After endOfDay connector you can add 4 parallel HTTP triggers and add logic to it.

**REFERENCES:** [Reference guide to workflow expression functions in Azure Logic Apps and Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#startofday)

Comment: Nice. Right now im going Recurrence -> HTTP Action, how do you make it to set it to Outputs()? What work flow are you using and doing?

Comment: @dev , It is the dynamic content that will be automatically generated.Please check this attached image https://i.imgur.com/6HuFeKI.png

Comment: Oh it seems like you are using the Compose action, i need to use HTTP request action to hit an endpoint and also pass in Headers.

Comment: In that case, you can use an HTTP connector and pass the content from previous steps. https://i.imgur.com/7YR3Cnx.png

Comment: So far I have Recurrence -> Http Action (4 parallel for different envs), can you show me your exact workflow from Recurrence -> ? what am i missing in between?

Comment: because i have not much points wont let me upload can you try this link
https://imgur.com/SVKPDAD

Comment: After checking the screenshot, we found that you have not added compose connector for your endOfDay.

Comment: btw does this work too? startOfDay(addDays(utcNow(), -1))

Comment: @dev If you meant `startOfDay(addDays(utcNow(), -1))` would give endOfDay then No. because adding -1 days to current day for startOfDay gives previous day's startOfDay if that makes sense